# Text in an equation

Tags: formatting, equations

This is best explained by example. Suppose I have the following:

```
\[
    \begin{align*}
    C_3 \rightarrow 6 automorphisms\\
    C_4 \rightarrow 8 automorphisms\\
    C_5 \rightarrow 10 automorphisms
    \end{align*}
\]
```

How can I get the word "automorphisms" to display as if it were not enclosed by the brackets?

Comment: Use `\intertext{automorphisms}` or if you want it in text mode simply use `\text{automorphisms}`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want? Using the `\text` command from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    C_3 &\rightarrow \text{$6$ automorphisms}\\
    C_4 &\rightarrow \text{$8$ automorphisms}\\
    C_5 &\rightarrow \text{$10$ automorphisms}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No fair ;) good one.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Sorry to nit pick but why go into text mode only go right back into math mode -- wouldn't it make sense to only have the text in `\text{}`? :-) And move the numbers before `\text{}`?

Comment: I would regard the "6 automorphisms" as a sentence fragment.  Putting it all in `\text` then gives it the usual spacing of a sentence.

Comment: @PeterGrill you're not nit picking at all ;-) Andrew Swann has answered in the meantime.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Ok, that is probably a better way of looking at it.