# Using Text in `eqnarray`

Tags: equations

I have been told that there was a way to use text within `eqnarray`; however, I have not been able to find or create any workable code.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `\text{}` with `amsmath` package.

Comment: @egreg Why not?  Whenever I use it, it works just fine.

Comment: @Mathematician Use `align`...

Comment: @Sigur Please transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Mathematician, as Dox said, use `align` and compare the result with `eqnarray`.

Comment: [Avoid eqnarray](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/15925 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75740/15925

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{left} &=& \text{right}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{align}
\text{left} &=  \text{right}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:** (by bbeeton, without consulting Sigur)

Consider the following slightly extended example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{left} &=& \text{middle} = \text{right}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{align*}
\text{left} &= \text{middle} = \text{right}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

(There isn't any facility for adding extra alignment points in `eqnarray`; they are
changed to "new line" breaks, after being reported as an error.)

*Now* is it obvious what the (or at least one) problem is with `eqnarray`?

Comment: I prefer the top version (which is `eqnarray`).  Why should I not use it?

Comment: @Mathematician, see the Ian comment above. He linked a pdf file. See it and also the section 2.2 therein.

Comment: @Mathematician: Look at the spacing of `\text{left}=\text{right}` and compare it to the spacing of `\begin{eqnarray} \text{left} &=& \text{right} \end{eqnarray}` - they're inconsistent.

Comment: @Sigur So, based on Section 2.2, using `eqnarray*` is good since that does not label the equation.

Comment: @Werner I am sorry, but I do not understand what you are talking about.  The spacing looks fine to me.

Comment: @Mathematician, OK. But and if you really need to number it? Also, see 2.3.

Comment: @Mathematician: Yes, the spacing looks fine to you in the separate environments and that's good. In a similar light, the discussion in [What is the Necessity of `$…$` Around Numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185193/5764) would probably seem superfluous to you... and that's fine as well. It's just that a majority of LaTeX users have conformed to *not* using `eqnarray` for reasons already mentioned. Just like I enjoy cream in my coffee doesn't mean that everyone *has* to follow what I do, so be happy with your choice and accept that (most) others have a different opinion.

Comment: @Mathematician Apart of the spacing, if your equation is long, `eqnarray` type the number of the equation *over* the equation, while `align` type the equation number below the equation.

Comment: @Werner You say that the majority of LaTeX users have conformed to not using `eqnarray` but no one has said explicitly WHY `align` is better.  I am just trying to figure out why.  I am not trying to give people a hard time.  I just want to know whether the preference of `align` over `eqnarray` is merely opinion or whether there is an actual reason.

Comment: Also, if `eqnarray` is so bad, why has it not been eliminated?

Comment: @Mathematician, if this would the case, we would have to change all our old files.

Comment: @Mathematician: I think most of that is covered in [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln) (and the links provided there). Many things remain in (La)TeX for legacy reasons, otherwise there would be no compatibility with a new/updated release (...things would break).